# Chrome AutoSelectCertificateForUrls Filter on Subject

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, registry, ssl-certificate

Currently encountering the same issue as this unanswered [Google Groups post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?noredirect=true&nomobile=true#!topic/chrome/RaWIFlgYXsU) from August 2016. Looking to filter the auto-selected certificate on another field such as Subject. [The Chromium documentation](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoSelectCertificateForUrls) is not particularly clear on what additional formats the `$FILTER` argument can take aside from the `ISSUER` variant.

So far I've tried:

```
"FILTER": {"MY_TARGET_CN"}
"FILTER": {"SUBJECT": "MY_TARGET_CN"}
"FILTER": {"SUBJECT": {"CN":"MY_TARGET_CN"}}
```

None have produced the desired results. Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and after many tests I decided to investigate the chromium sources and discovered the following:
There is implementation only for ISSUER filters, there is even a "TODO" in the sources as can be seen in the **chrome_content_browser_client.cc** file on line **585**:

```
...
bool CertMatchesFilter(const net::X509Certificate& cert,
                   const base::DictionaryValue& filter) {
// TODO(markusheintz): This is the minimal required filter implementation.
// Implement a better matcher.

// An empty filter matches any client certificate since no requirements are
// specified at all.
if (filter.empty())
  return true;

std::string common_name;
if (filter.GetString("ISSUER.CN", &common_name) &&
  (cert.issuer().common_name == common_name)) {
  return true;
}
  return false;
}
...
```

An bug report already exists in:[bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=707787)

Comment: I have the same problem and I wonder if it will ever be implemented :(