# Login to WebPage using Certificate from Java

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate

I have a webpage which demands for a SSL Certificate, then uses the SSL Certificates to autofill the username, then waits for the user to input the user password and click on a button to proceed to the application itself.

What I would like to do is to create a little Java application which is automatically logging the user passing Certificate, Username and password and then open the application in the default browser.

I was thinking of 
1 - sending an initial GET request to collect the Session ID, 
2 - send a POST request passing the Certificate, Username and Password 
3 - open the requested secure webpage in a browser.

I know how to use a HttpsURLConnection to perform the first 2 steps, however I'm not sure if this workflow makes sense as I don't know how to perform step 3 once I am authenticated.

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Thank you all for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello everyone just writing this solution for those that have a similar problem as maybe they will have to struggle less.

We have a Cloud solution which requires UserName + Password + an SSL Certificate to login.
I wanted to have the possibility to open a specific page in a browser window passing a parameter without having to login and or having to select the Certificate from the list of available certificates.

So my initial approach was not working as I hoped, therefore I started watching into using Selenium to Open a the Web Page passing parameters.
It worked fine and I have configured the program to ask the username and password the first time the program is launched and save them in an encrypted file in the Windows user profile.

Only obstacle I still had was to automatically select the certificate out of the list of available certificates which is presented by the browser.
There are a lot of different posts about this issue, and the majority are not really scalable, until i found one solution: Chrome offers the possibility to set one specific Policy which is called "AutoSelectCertificateForUrls" which allows to specify one Certificate for a specific URL that is automatically selected. So I configured the installer to set this Parameter (needs to be set in the Windows Registry), and this did the trick.
Each Windows user will have his certificate stored in the Current User Certificate Storage  and his/her credentials are stored for each user in the Windows User Profile.

The only limitation is that for the time being you can only specify the Certificate Issuer company (therefore if you have multiple certificates from the same company only the first certificate will work), but apparently the Chromium team is working on being able to filter on the "Subject" (this question also helped me with this:
[Chrome AutoSelectCertificateForUrls Filter on Subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480938/chrome-autoselectcertificateforurls-filter-on-subject). I hope this helps others.

Comment: Could you be more detailed? How do you set the option/preference (which one is it?) to the driver to set the AutoSelectCertificateForUrls to something like  {{“pattern”:”[*.]abhay.com”,”filter”:{“ISSUER”:{“CN”:”ABHAY_ISSUER”}}}}?? Also, I havent found AutoSelectCertificateForUrls among args or preferences of Chrome. Thank you